# page fault in operating system.(invalid addressing or page not in main memory)

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-fault, demand-paging

i am reading about page faults in demand paging. page faults happen when
1) the memory being is accessed is illegal
2)the page is valid but not present in main memory

i read that with valid-invalid bit you can tell if the memory is not in logical
address space,because the corresponding bit will be marked invalid.

the same valid-invalid bit is used to identify the above 2 condition.

my question how does the os know if the memory being accessed is illegal
or if the page is valid but not in main memory with just one valid-invalid bit?
thank you!

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1):

In **Demand Paging** if the `valid-invalid bit` is set(1), it means that the associated `page` is both legal and in memory. However if the `valid-invalid bit` is not set(0), it means the following:

1. Either the `page` is not valid. It means that page is not in process `logical address space`. **OR**
2. The corresponding `page`  is on `disk`.

The invalid page access causes a **page-fault trap**. And we handle it in the following way. Quoting from *Operating Systems principles by Silberschatz, Galvin, Gagne*

> 1. We check an internal table(usually kept with the process control block) for this process to determine whether the reference was a valid
>      or an invalid memory access.
> 2. If the reference was invalid, we terminate the process. If it was valid, but we have not yet brought in that page, we now page it in.
> 3. We find a free frame(by taking one from the free frame list, for example).
> 4. We schedule a disk operation to read the desired page into the newly allocated frame.
> 5. When the disk read is complete, we modify the internal table kept with the process and the page table to indicate that the page is now
>      in memory.
> 6. We restart the instruction that was interrupted by the trap. The process can now access the page as though it had always been in
>      memory.